# Disallow typing of few of characters e.g.'<', '>' in all input textboxes using jquery

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, webforms

**How do I achieve this:-**

When user types character like `'abcd'` and then `'>'`(an invalid character for my application), I want to set the text back to `'abcd'`. Better if we can cancel the input itself as we do in winforms application. This should happen when user is typing and not on a click of button.

I want this to be applied on all text boxes in my web page. This will be easy if the solution is jQuery based. May be something which will start like this.

 `$("input[type='text']")`

**SOLUTION**
I used both of the answer provided by @jAndy and @Iacopo (Sorry, couldn't mark as answer to both) as below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //makes sure that user cannot enter < or > sign in text boxes.
  $("input:text").keyup(purgeInvalidChars)
      .blur(purgeInvalidChars)
      .bind('keypress', function(event) {
        if (event.which === 62 || event.which === 60)
          return (false);
      });
  function purgeInvalidChars() {
    if (this.value != this.value.replace(/[<>]/g, '')) {
      this.value = this.value.replace(/[<>]/g, '');
    }
  }
});
```

Though one issue still remained i.e. It doesn't allow user to select text in the textbox and this only happens on chrome, work fine on IE (for the first time :D), not tested on firefox. It would be glad if anyone can find solution for that or hope people at Google solves it :D.

**UPDATE**
I solved it by `if (this.value != this.value.replace(/[<>]/g, ''))` check. Also updated solution.

Thanks again to all the answerers.

Comment: Hopefully you already realize this, but note that client-side validation will not prevent users from submitting input with a '>', so you will still need to perform input validation on the server side as well.

Comment: Thanks Brain! ASP.NET takes care of it. It throws dangerous input exception and for me it will redirect to custom error page.

Comment: Remember that user side input validation is never enough. You should always validate input on the server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should catch the 'keyup' and 'blur' events and attach them to a function that bonifies the input: don't forget that the user can paste an invalid sequence of characters.

So for example

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(purgeInvalidChars).blur(purgeInvalidChars)

function purgeInvalidChars()
{
   this.value = this.value.replace(/[<>]/g, ''); 
}
```

surely you will improve the regexp, maybe replacing all characters except the enabled ones.

Sorry, I can't test my code, so you should take it *cum grano salis* :-)

Comment: @lacopo - This works, except that you should add the `g` global identifier to the regex just in case someone does a copy/paste with more than one invalid character.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the paste thing. I had missed it completely This works but user is not able to select the text in the text box. Can anything be done for that?

Comment: Yes, you should avoid to replace the text if `event.which` is not a real character (i.e. it is an arrow, or Home etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Example (keypress):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:text').bind('keypress', function(event){

    if(event.which === 62 || event.which === 60)
       return(false);
    });
});​
```

Example (keydown):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input:text').bind('keydown', function(event){
    if(event.which === 226)
       return(false);
  });
});​
```

Just make use of the `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` functions for events. Those are triggered by returning (`false`) within an event handler.

In this example, I just check for the keycode of `<` and `>` which is thankfully on the same key. If we hit that code, we just prevent the default behavior.

**Reference**: [.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), [.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: Not sure what you were testing on but this does not work at all on a Windows machine, and the keycode of the < is 188 and 190 for >.  Also, browser I used was chrome.

Comment: @ryanulit: using winXP on chrome. for `keydown` it is 226 for me, both `which` and `keyCode`. No reason to downvote this.

Comment: this also not working I'm able to enter `<` and `>` characters. I'm using win7

Comment: @Ismail: try the keypress variant

Comment: Keypress variant works perfectly. :). Thank you v v much @jAndy

Comment: @Ismail: yepa, there is really no need to bump your site with some plugin just for an easy task like that.

Comment: @Ismail: `which` is normalized through jQuery, so it should work cross-browser, cross-plattform for `keypress`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#textBox').keyup(function(e){
            var myText = $('#textBox').val(); 
            myText =  myText.replace(">", "");
            myText =  myText.replace("<", "");
            $('#textBox').val(myText);
        });
```

-- Update --

`keyup` instead `keypress`

Comment: I don't know why this would be downvoted. It is not the most efficient implementation, but it is a correct solution.

Comment: I see the issue. You would need to change it to `keyup` instead of `keypress`.